# How Can I access the textfields in static TableViewcells without creating referencing outlet?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield, iboutlet

I have lot of text fields statically placed in static TableViewcells. How can access the text in it without creating referencing outlet for each textfield? I have tried taking subviews of cell. It's not working. Any alternatives?

I tried this. It's not working.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView
                   cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     for (UIView *subview in [cell subviews]){
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
            UITextField *inputField = (UITextField *)subview;
            NSLog(@"%@",inputField.text);
        }
     }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an IBOutletCollection. That lets you connect them all to one array, where you can access them by index, or use setValue:forKey: to address them all at once.

Comment: I couldn't create referncing outlet or collection of tableview :(
but I'm able create outlet collection for cell.any idea?

Comment: @Harikrishnan, I don't understand what you mean by "collection of table view". Are you trying to make one collection for all the cells?

Comment: I got it now. thanks. I wasn't familiar with outlet collections, thats why. Issue has been solved now. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can always iterate through every subviews of your cell to find a `UITextField`. Something like:

```
NSArray *subviews = [cell subviews];
for (view in subviews) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        //Do what you want with your UITextField
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working for static cells.                   

for (UIView *subview in [cell subviews]){
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
            UITextField *inputField = (UITextField *)subview;
            NSLog(@"%@",inputField.text);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Set `tag` to your `textField`:

   ```
   textField.tag = kTextFieldTag;
   ```
2. Retrieve `subView` of `cell` with that `tag`

   ```
   UITextField *refTextField = [cell viewWithTag:kTextFieldTag];
   ```

Here, `kTextFieldTag` is constant.