# Can i access text of label or textfield without creating outlet in swift 3.0?

Tags: swift

I'm new in swift development.I'm trying to access text of label without creating outlet. I set tag to label and tried to get text.

I referred this link 
[How Can I access the textfields in static TableViewcells without creating referencing outlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824608/how-can-i-access-the-textfields-in-static-tableviewcells-without-creating-refere)

I succeed in that but i want to navigate that text to next ViewController programmatically, but not able to do that. Can anyone help me for that.

I tried following code

```
for view: UIView in self.view.subviews {
        if (view is UILabel)  {
            let stortboard = UIStoryboard.init(name:"Main",bundle:nil)
            let vc =  stortboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "SecondViewControllerID") as? SecondViewController

            let lbl: UILabel? = (view as? UILabel)

            vc?.lblData = lbl?.text
            print(lbl?.text ?? "not found")
            //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
            self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

Comment: set tag to your label and try to get viewWithTag

if let foundView = self.view.viewWithTag(yourtag number) as? UILabel {
       print(lbl?.text ?? "not found")
}

Comment: Do you have variable `lblData` in `SecondViewController` ?

Comment: @Shital you need to make one String variable into SecondViewController and set it into currentViewController"vc?.variableName = lbl?.text " and then  use it into SecondViewController after push viewController

Comment: yes i have variable lblData in SecondViewController.

Comment: @Muhammad Noman tried viewWithTag. getting nil.

Comment: i thing you did not setTag value in your stroyboard i post as answer with screen shot . sorry for late rep i saw your problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it works. Make sure you have `lblData:String!` in `SecondViewController`

Try this

```
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if (view is UILabel)  {
            let stortboard = UIStoryboard.init(name:"Main",bundle:nil)
            let vc =  stortboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "SecondViewControllerID") as? SecondViewController
            let lbl: UILabel? = (view as? UILabel)
            vc?.lblData = lbl?.text
            print(lbl?.text ?? "not found")
            self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find through tag then you can use viewWithTag as described.

Set tag of text field as follows :

[image]

```
//Get One By One with Tag
if let txtField1 = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as? UITextField {
    print(txtField1.text!)
}
```

Hope it help you.